# Process each line from text file and delete related files from disk

Tags: shell, text-processing, rm

I used the find command to find several files and folders and output them to a text file like so:

```
nohup find /oradba -name '*soapr*' 2>/dev/null >find_soapr_db40.txt &
```

So instead of displaying my results to the screen, I sent them to the file. Normally, I could just append "-exec rm -rf {} \;" to the end of my find command to find related files and delete them at the same time.

```
find / -name '*soatst*' 2>/dev/null -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

But **how can I run a command to process each line from the .txt file and delete the files they are referencing from the disk?**

The text file contains items like the following:

```
/oradba/app/oracle/admin/soaprod2
/oradba/app/oracle/admin/soaprd2
/oradba/app/oracle/product/10.2.0.5/db_aprpsu/dbs/initsoaprd2.ora
/oradba/app/oracle/product/10.2.0.5/db_aprpsu/dbs/hc_soaprd2.dat
/oradba/app/oracle/product/10.2.0.5/db_aprpsu/dbs/alert_soaprd2.log
/oradba/app/oracle/product/10.2.0.5/db_aprpsu/dbs/spfilesoaprd2.ora
```

Answer (score 2):

Danger: it is perfectly legal for Unix paths to contain newlines. If any of your paths contain newlines, this is potentially dangerous. Consider using `\0` to separate the filenames instead by using GNU `find`'s `-print0` option, and then processing them using GNU `xargs`' `-0` option.

---

You can use the following:

```
files=()

while IFS= read -r file; do
    files+=( "$file" )
done < ind_soapr_db40.txt

rm -r -- "${files[@]}"
```

You *could* call `rm` each time directly in the `for` loop, but that would be slower than populating the list of files and processing them in one invocation of `rm`.

If you have bash4+, you can instead use `mapfile`:

```
mapfile -t files < ind_soapr_db40.txt
rm -r -- "${files[@]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

This Perl one-liner should work even if your file names have newlines:

```
perl -000ne 'unlink (/(.+?\/[^\/]+)\n/sg);' list
```

To recursively delete directories and their contents, try this:

```
perl -000ne 'use File::Path; rmtree (/(.+?\/[^\/]+)\n/sg);' list
```

#### Explanation

- `-000` : activate paragraph mode, reads the entire file at once.
- `-ne` : read the file given as an argument (`-n`) and run the script passed by `-e`.
- `/(.+?\/[^\/]+)\n/sg` : look for any character, followed by a `/`, then as many non-`/` characters as possible (including newlines thanks to the [`s` modifier](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Modifiers)) until the next newline. Since file names cannot contain `/`, this should select the whole path and separate ea
- Pass the matches (file names) returned by the regular expression above to [`unlink()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unlink.html) to delete them.

Comment: I like this solution! It seems to work really well, but how do I get it to remove directories recursively? Your suggestion is only removing matching files.

Comment: @user2554129 see updated answer for a version that deletes directories. However, unless your file names actually do contain new lines (which is possible but not very likely), use \@ChrisDown's answer which is the classic *nix way.